# sql equivalent to for each

Tags: sql, join, impala

I am querying in Imapla tables that were created in MySQL and imported in HDFS with HIVE.
I have search and I know this is not officially supported or encouraged in SQL, but it conveys what I want to do. Here are the tables I am working with:

```
Customers Table:
+---------+---------+
| cust_id | zipcode |
+---------+---------+
| 1       | 94964   |
| 2       | 98577   |
| 3       | 52593   |
| 4       | 43972   |
| 5       | 95298   |
+---------+---------+

Orders Table
+---------+----------+
| cust_id | order_id |
+---------+----------+
| 1       | 11       |
| 2       | 12       |
| 3       | 13       |
| 4       | 14       |
| 5       | 15       |
+---------+----------+

Order_Details Table
+----------+---------+
| order_id | prod_id |
+----------+---------+
| 11       | 123     |
| 11       | 124     |
| 11       | 125     |
| 14       | 126     |
| 15       | 127     |
+----------+---------+

Products Table
+---------+-------------+
| prod_id | shipping_wt |
+---------+-------------+
| 123     | 1           |
| 124     | 1           |
| 125     | 1           |
| 126     | 8           |
| 126     | 2           |
+---------+-------------+
```

Ultimately I want to return the total_wt for each order (calculated from all prod_ids within one order_id). I have already joined all the tables:

```
SELECT ord.order_id, cus.cust_id, cus.zipcode, ordet.prod_id, prod.shipping_wt 
FROM customers cus
JOIN orders ord
ON cus.cust_id = ord.cust_id
JOIN order_details ordet
ON ordet.order_id = ord.order_id
JOIN products prod
ON prod.prod_id = ordet.prod_id;
```

When thinking how to do this, I thought of for each loops but I know that is not supported. What other methods could accomplish this same thing? I know I need to do a SUM() of all shipping_wts for all prod_ids in one order_id but I'm just not sure how.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I am really try to learn and I want to understand the mindset in approaching something like this.

Thank you!

Comment: What's wrong with SUM() and GROUP BY?

Comment: I am aware of those functions but I'm not sure how to perform that on each order and for all prod_id shipping_wts in each order.

Answer (score 1):

Adding SUM and GROUP BY (and some formatting to make it easier to see what I've done):

```
SELECT 
    ord.order_id,
    SUM(prod.shipping_wt) 
FROM 
    order_details ordet
JOIN        
    products prod
ON 
    prod.prod_id = ordet.prod_id
GROUP BY
    ord.order_id;
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I tested it though and it returns 2 for order_id=6340939. I then ran a separate query to display all shipping_wts for all prod_id that have order_id=6340939 and I got three products that each have a shipping_wt=1? Maybe I didn't explain something? So it does seem to be summing correctly.

Comment: If you really only want order_id and shipping_wt, delete the other columns from the SELECT and GROUP BY.

Comment: In your test data, I don't even see an order_id 6340939, but I'm guessing that it has duplicates on one of the other grouped by columns - if I had to guess based solely on column names, I'd say it's probably prod_id.

Comment: sorry I just realized that my test data is not a very good representation. Let me edit it to be simpler and then retry

Comment: ok I have changed the data to reflect what I saw. So your query returned "2"    when it should be "3"

Comment: Edited my answer.  Give it a shot.

Comment: Your edited answer seems to work but I would like to be able to return the zip_code and cust_id as well in the final output. When I try and add that back in though, it breaks it again as described before. I'm trying to figure out why. EDIT: there are some slight typos in your query: 1) "ord" should be "ordet"